# Connection issues with Linksys WRT54GL / Tomato

Tags: router, tomato

I recently purchased a new router, and decided to put Tomato on it for some of the fancy features, like graphs. Only problem is, now I've installed it I can't connect to the internet any more!

What I've done so far is plug the router in, connect to it wirelessly, and upgrade the firmware to the right version for my router. This went swimmingly, the router restarted, and everything's Tomatoey. Except it won't, now, connect to the internet, and I'm entirely unsure what I've missed.

My old router was a BT Homehub, my ISP is BT (British Telecommunications). I'm a bit lost, this is the first time I've done any of this 3rd party firmware stuff.

EDIT: Oh dear, it appears the homehub was also functioning as a modem - something this linksys does not do. Eep.

Comment: oh, so now you don't have a modem?

Comment: @studiohack: Looks like it. Entirely unsure how to proceed, here.

Comment: your ISP should provide you with a proper modem, or try @Cry Havok's suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup - the HomeHub is a DSL router.  You either need to put it back in or replace it with a functional DSL router.  Either way you can connect the Linksys to the HomeHub or DSL modem.

---

You may want to read [this thread](http://www.myopenrouter.com/forum/thread/18757/DD-WRT-No-Internet/) on another forum.  They're using DD-WRT but similar things apply.  You need to ensure that the Linksys is using a different LAN IP range, that it's still doing NAT etc.

When it's connected check:

1. Can you SSH onto the Linksys and ping the LAN IP of the HomePlug
2. Can you ping the HomeHub from behind the Linksys on a wired connection

Comment: You mention connecting the linksys to the homehub, but I'm having a bit of trouble with that. I've stuck an Ethernet cable between one of the ports on the homehub and the port marked "internet" on the linksys, but still getting no connectivity from the linksys (though it's fine through the hub)

Comment: Oh, duh! They were both on the same subnet, it works now! Thank you, you're delicious <3